# FFmpeg/Avconv: Scaling Filter "Error when evaluating the expression"

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, libav

I'm trying to scale a video with FFmpeg with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'" output_320x240_boxed.png
```

This is taken verbatim from the FFmpeg wiki at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg.

When I copy and paste it into bash I receive the following error:

```
[scale @ 0x23a0980] [Eval @ 0x7fff165851e0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)'
[scale @ 0x23a0980] [Eval @ 0x7fff165851e0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'
Error when evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'
Error opening filters!
```

I've tried every combination of escaping the various commas, quotes, and parentheses I can think of with varying results, but the bottom line is that no matter what I do, FFmpeg does not evaluate the expression correctly and throws an error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Full output:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:53:28 with gcc 4.8.1
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, image2, from 'input.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 535x346 [PAR 100:100 DAR 535:346], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj420p' for codec 'png', auto-selecting format 'rgb24'
[buffer @ 0x100b400] w:535 h:346 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[scale @ 0x100a980] [Eval @ 0x7fff33214ee0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)'
[scale @ 0x100a980] [Eval @ 0x7fff33214ee0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'
Error when evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Updated with full output.

Comment: Information on the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki) is only for `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg. You are using a fake, unsupported, and buggy "`ffmpeg`" from a misleading fork. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017) for more info on that. Try getting a static build of `ffmpeg` via links at the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page.